# Spawn prefabs from list one by one when trigger is touched

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to spawn one gameobject from a list of gameobjects each time I touch the trigger with the controller.

But when I do this, all the game objects from the list spawn together at the same time. I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem and make them spawn one at a time instead, where the next touch spawns the next object in the list, and so on.

[image: Trigger Button]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform spawnPoint;
    //public GameObject Prefab;
    public List<GameObject> items = new List<GameObject>();

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        //GameObject Prefab = new GameObject("prefab");

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(items[i], spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
            Debug.Log("Hello World" +i);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to spawn one GameObject per touch, you could store the spawnIndex outside the method, and increment it by one each time you spawn.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Transform spawnPoint; //public GameObject Prefab;
  public List items = new List();
  private int spawnIndex = 0;

  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
  {
    //GameObject Prefab = new GameObject("prefab");
    int i = spawnIndex++ % items.Count;
    // int i = Random.Range(0, items.Count); // for random each time
    Instantiate(items[i], spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
    Debug.Log("Hello World" + i);
  }
}
```